# Are there ICD-10 codes for space?

Tags: crewed-spaceflight, microgravity, medical, hypergravity

Today (October 1, 2015) the diagnosis codes known as [ICD-10 went live in the US](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICD-10#United_States). I was wondering if there are any that are specific to spacecraft, space stations, or hypo- or hyper-gravity?

Comment: I no longer have access to the reference, but there are/were space related ICD-9 codes as well. It was boggling how specific some codes were(not just the space ones.) Many times looking through that book, see something and think there is no way **that** has happened more than once...

Comment: @Mr.Mindor you are correct I just checked and found [E845.0 ACCIDENT INVOLVING SPACECRAFT INJURING OCCUPANT OF SPACECRAFT](https://www.cms.gov/medicare-coverage-database/staticpages/icd-9-code-lookup.aspx?KeyWord=E845.0&bc=AAAAAAAAAAAEAA%3d%3d&)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, [shared by MichaelT in The Pod Bay](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/24411155#24411155) just recently:

- [2015/16 ICD-10-CM Diagnosis Code V95.43: Spacecraft collision injuring occupant](http://www.icd10data.com/ICD10CM/Codes/V00-Y99/V95-V97/V95-/V95.43)

There are others that you can search for by keywords on [ICD10Data.com](http://www.icd10data.com/), for example:

- [2015/16 ICD-10-CM Diagnosis Code X52: Prolonged stay in weightless environment](http://www.icd10data.com/ICD10CM/Codes/V00-Y99/X52-X58/X52-/X52)
- [2015/16 ICD-10-CM Diagnosis Code T75.81XA: Effects of abnormal gravitation [G] forces, initial encounter](http://www.icd10data.com/ICD10CM/Codes/S00-T88/T66-T78/T75-/T75.81XA)

---

Some of them are billable items, like [2015/16 ICD-10-CM Diagnosis Code T75.82XA: Effects of weightlessness, initial encounter](http://www.icd10data.com/ICD10CM/Codes/S00-T88/T66-T78/T75-/T75.82XA) that *can be used to indicate a diagnosis for reimbursement purposes*. There go them [vomit comet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced_gravity_aircraft) profits :)

Comment: The entire V95.4 range is more like these.

Answer (score 0):

Spacecraft collision injuring occupant is actually listed as V95.42XD. In ICD-9 the code is E845.0

You can find the info here: [icd10.nuemd.com/icd-10/codes/V95.42XD.](http://icd10.nuemd.com/icd-10/codes/V95.42XD.)

Comment: There's no discrepancy, both ([1](http://icd10.nuemd.com/icd-10/codes/V95.42), [2](http://www.icd10data.com/ICD10CM/Codes/V00-Y99/V95-V97/V95-/V95.42)) list V95.42 as _"Forced landing of spacecraft injuring occupant"_. Both also list V95.43 ([1](http://icd10.nuemd.com/icd-10/codes/V95.43), [2](http://www.icd10data.com/ICD10CM/Codes/V00-Y99/V95-V97/V95-/V95.43)) as _"Spacecraft collision injuring occupant"_. I fail to see the point of posting this as a standalone answer just to say there's [yet another site with searchable ICD-10 database](https://encrypted.google.com/#q=icd+10+search).

Comment: I edited the question to remove the second link, it felt like spam and did not add value to the answer.